# How can I keep the cell blank until any data is entered in another cell in the same row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: Trying to keep cell blank until any data is entered in another cell in the same row].
Trying to keep cell blank until any data is entered in another cell in the same row.
There is already a long formula in the cell I need to stay blank but I have no idea how to add an additional `ISBLANK` formula along with it.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. The cell in column A row 65 is already empty, right? Can you please simplify the question as much as possible, leaving out irrelevant columns out of it? If you can, please include dummy output with what you want to achieve.

Comment: As I understand it, you need COUNTA() instead of ISBLANK() - something like `=IF(COUNTA($A65:$I65)=0,"",<your long formula IF(SUM(...>)`

Comment: You should be able to use `AND(ISBLANK($A65:$H65))` as an alternative to `COUNTA($A65:$H65)=0` in the formula suggested by @JohnSUN . Both should achieve your goal.

Comment: =IF(SUM(I65:L65)>0,"Fail","Pass") is the current formula in M, where we need to see PASS or FAIL based on the selections in D:H. Because the words PASS and FAIL are adding up as a count for my overall average, I need for that cell (M) to stay blank if nothing is entered in any one cell (D:H). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It does make sense. Change the formula for cell `M65` to `=IF(AND(ISBLANK(A65:H65),"",IF(SUM(I65:L65)>0,"Fail","Pass"))`. Now `M65` has 3 possibilities, the zero-length text string, the text string "Fail" or the  string string "Pass". If you are calculating your "Pass" rate count the number of passes and divide it by the sum of the number of passes and the number of fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called a nested if, plus the ability to return a "blank" cell:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(D65),ISBLANK(E65),...,ISBLANK(H65)), "", IF(SUM(I65:L65)>0,"Fail","Pass"))
```

Sadly you cannot return a truely blank cell, since a cell with a formula isn't blank. But you can return an empty string "" so that it looks blank.

You can distinguish between a blank cell and an empty string in Excel e.g. ISBLANK(M65) vs (M65="")

Lastly, you should be able to use ISBLANK and OR in array format:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(D65:H65)), "", IF(SUM(I65:L65)>0,"Fail","Pass"))
```

but note on old Excel versions this might give you problems, not might require you to confirm the formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER rather than just the ENTER key.

Comment: OMG! That is awesome! It worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Np! Kindly checkmark the solution so others may know it has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(A1:L1)=12,"",IF(SUM(I1:L1)>0,"Fail","Pass"))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one @Lee ,, you get +10 ☺